# Rails form_for uses POST instead of PUT

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms

I'm attempting to create a button that updates a single field on my `Client` model but it keeps creating a POST instead of a PUT request:

```
<% @consultations.each do |consult| %>
    ...
    <%= form_for consult.client, remote: true, :html => { :method => :put } do |f| %>
        <%= f.hidden_field :verified_for_stats, value: true %>
        <%= f.submit "Use for stats", class: "btn btn-success btn-sm" %>
    <% end -%>
    ...
<% end %>
```

When I look inside the form element in the dev tools I see the following instead of `<input name="_method" type="hidden" value="put" />`:

```
<input type="hidden" name="_method" value="aO8Syz5d9LjeGOc5H7k1HCfu6pap9aukjeZyUcDj1p/QrCAs4LbbINLKVT2MBXGW39ZvmNiqTgL8Tiep5RQQSA==">
```

I've tried replacing the `form_for` line with each of the following but still got the same result.  Not sure if my syntax is still off or what's going on:

```
<%= form_for consult.client, method: "put", remote: true do |f| %>
<%= form_for consult.client, method: :put, remote: true do |f| %>
<%= form_for consult.client, method: "patch", remote: true do |f| %>
<%= form_for consult.client, method: :patch, remote: true do |f| %>
```

What can I do to make this request a PUT?

Comment: This is highly atypical.  `form_for consult.client, method: :patch, remote: true` should generate a `<input type="hidden" name="_method" value="put">`. Using `html: { method: :put }` is less idiomatic but works. It does not matter if you use a string or symbol for the http method. I would treat this as a bug and try to create a minimal verifiable example that reproduces the bug. Usually that lets you track it down.

Comment: Usually you don't even have to specify the method. Rails calls `.persisted?` on the model instance and figures out if its POST or PATCH and which path to use. PATCH has been used instead of PUT for updates for years.

Comment: @max yeah I figured as much which is why I'm confused since the `client` is in the database already.

Comment: Have you tried using `view source` in the browser? That will let you eliminate any client side tomfoolery.

Comment: @max not sure what that is

Comment: @max maybe there's a better strategy to update a single field from a button?

Comment: In chrome you right click and select "View Page Source". That shows the raw html sent by the server.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/202229/discussion-between-jeremy-thomas-and-max).

Comment: @JeremyThomas can you please the relevant routes which are created for the `consult.client` end point?

Comment: It renders `action="/clients/3687"`.  I removed the `method: :put` and now it's rendering properly?  I have no idea why, but it seems to be working now.